# How to add Vertical scrolling to a Canvas using script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to add Vertical scrolling to a Canvas using a script.
I'm adding N number of GameObject to the Canvas and placing them one after the other. 
Now I want to add a vertical scroll to the canvas but I'm not sure how to proceed.
Please Help me out.
Thank You.

```
GameObject instance = Instantiate (Resources.Load ("Object", typeof (GameObject))) as GameObject;
instance.transform.SetParent (GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Canvas").transform, true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you want is a ScrollView object which scrolls vertically.
So according to Unity's [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UICreateFromScripting.html) the best way to create the UI elements runtime is by creating a Prefab of that UI Element, set the properties according to your need.

So in your case You need to create a prefab of ScrollView which has the Horizontal set as false and Vertical set as True in the ScrollRect component and then make a prefab of that object and use it in your script to instantiate it.

```cs
public GameObject scrollPrefab;
void SpawnVerticalScrollView()
{
   GameObject instance = Instantiate (scrollPrefab,GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Canvas").transform) as GameObject;   
}
```

And as you can see I have also assigned the parent to the instantiated object right away in the same line.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you don't use the function `Resources.Load`, because the Unity says: "Don't use it. Use of the Resources folder makes fine-grained memory management more difficult. So you need to have a created prefab with your scrolling component and add this prefab link to your main script that controlling UI objects in the Canvas by the editor.  When you need to use the scrolling prefab just use "Instantiate" function. Attache your controlling script to the Canvas object. For example:

```
    public GameObject scrollingPrefab;

    public void CreatePrefab(){         
    GameObject currentPrefab = Instantiate(scrollingPrefab, gameObject.transform);     
}
```

Also, the bad way of creating objects is using the function `FindGameObjectWithTag` and other "Find".